# What is the difference between root mean square, and standard deviation?

Tags: probability, standard-deviation, means

I am currently working through the Feynman Lectures, chapter 6: Probability.
I have reached his problem of the "random walk".

After deriving this and getting some root mean square, wouldn't this just be the same as finding the standard deviation? The standard deviation is the root of the mean of the squared data. Isn't that also just the root mean square?

Also, what exactly are the implications of the root mean square, what does it even mean in regards to our problem?

http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_06.html

Comment: Yes, RMS=STD. Could you clarify your last question?

Comment: @A.S. Okay, that makes a lot more sense. 

My last question was just, what exactly is the root mean square, why do we use it?

Comment: It is one of the measures of how much around the mean the quantity is dispersed (that's why sometimes its square is sometimes called "dispersion"). For a constant quantity, RMS is zero, for example. It is used everywhere mostly because variance (which is STD^2) is mathematically easily tractable: $var(X+Y)=var(X)+var(Y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent (or even just uncorrelated).

Comment: Another nice property of variance is that $var(X-c)$ is minimized when $c=E(X)$.

Comment: In many applications the standard deviation is not taken by the mean $\bar x= \sum / n$ but from the modified $\bar x_1= \sum / (n-1) $ (per default when you have a sample and intend to given an estimate for the sd in the population). I've not seen this with the rms

Comment: RMS is not the same as standard deviation, as another user pointed out. Standard deviation accounts for the deviation of individual data points from the mean, whereas RMS accounts for the absolute magnitude of those data points as well. Only when the mean is zero are RMS and standard deviation the same.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

in the case of standard deviation, the mean is removed out from obsevations, but in root mean square the mean is not removed. however in the case of noise where the mean is zero, the two concept are the same. I hope that this is the difference. see: http://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/2004-11/1100200293.Ph.r.html

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE and thanks for tackling an open Question.  It is desirable to quote from or summarize what a Reader will find at the specified link when this supplies the main content of your Answer, so that an informed decision can be made whether to follow your link.  Please review [How to write a good Answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Upvoting the answer to counter the erroneous comment that "this does not provide an answer to the question."

Comment: When do I use the sd and when rms?